# Indicate whether network connectivity is possible using isavailable()

Tags: android

I have tried this code to check my mobile network connectivity

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = 
        connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);


        if( mobile.isAvailable() ){
            Toast tst = Toast.makeText(this, "There is a network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
              tst.show();   
                        }
        else
        {
            Toast tst = Toast.makeText(this, "There is No network",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
              tst.show();   
        }
```

The program always says "There is No network", although, there is a network.
Maybe because I am using a 2G Sim Card and this method works for 3G. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want telephony status, not data status.

Try with a different API.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html

This may work.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

May be handy aswell.

Comment: This looks relevant. I have tried 
 ServiceState ss = new ServiceState();
 Toast tt = Toast.makeText(this,"This is state "+  ss.getState(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
 tt.show();
 
It always shows 1 which is State out of service. IT should be (0) State_in service

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
try{

     if(mobile.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
          //connected
     }else{
          //not connected
     }

}catch (Exception e){
    // if device doesnt have mobile
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still says "not connected" .

Answer (score 0):

I use this to check network connectivity, hope it helps :)

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context applicationContext){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try{ 
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException npe){

        return false; //Airplane mode is on
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine for detecting Wifi Network. When I turn the Wifi off, it returns false. When I turn the Wifi on, it returns on. But this is not what I need. I want to detect the mobile network availability for example when my phone becomes out of coverage area.